# Firebase Array Fetches Not Loading on Page Load

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angular-promise

```
// Movements Controller
app.controller("MovementsCtrl", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$filter", "$timeout", "$route", function($scope, $rootScope, $filter, $timeout, $route) {
  $rootScope.pageName = "Movements";

  var date = new Date();
  var currentDate = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'MM/dd/yyyy');

  $scope.labels = [];
  $scope.data = [];
  $scope.recordsArray = []; // Converts records object into an array.
  console.log($scope.recordsArray);

  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      $rootScope.userID = user.uid;

      // Run query to pull user records.
      $timeout(function() {
        var userID = $rootScope.userID;
        var query = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID +'/movements/').orderByChild('created');

        query.on("value", function(snapshot) {
            $scope.records = snapshot.val();

              angular.forEach($scope.records, function(element) {
                $scope.recordsArray.push(element);
                $scope.labels.push(element.name);
                $scope.data.push(element.weight);
              });
        });
      });
    } else {
      console.log("not signed in");
    }
  });

  $scope.addRecord = function() {
    console.log("Pushed");
    var recordID = database.ref().push().key;
    var userID = $rootScope.userID;

    database.ref('users/' + userID + '/movements/' + recordID).set({
      user: userID,
      name: "Front Squat",
      sets: 5,
      reps: 5,
      weight: 350,
      created: currentDate
    });
    $route.reload();
  }
}]);
```

For some reason my page loads before the arrays in my JS load, rendering an empty page.  I've tried wrapping everything in an init() function and loading that, but still the same issue.  Can anyone help me figure out how to pre-load my JS arrays beforehand or is there another solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Your arrays are populated by an asynchronous request; one thing you can do is put an ng-if on your template and only load once there is data in one or all of your arrays. Also since you are using ng-route you can put a resolve in your route definition so the page will only render after the promise is resolved.

Comment: how can you be sure that the JS are loading and the API calls are running properly

Comment: @ModarNa because if I go from one page to another, everything loads properly.  But if I am on this page and refresh, nothing loads.

Comment: any console errors

Comment: @ModarNa no errors

Comment: if you put an `alert()` after fetching the data does it fire

Comment: @ModarNa yes it does

Comment: this means that controller is functioning properly ,, i`m guessing that your problem is with the data structrure returned from api or something similliar ,, try debugging like putting `alert(query)` , `alert(element)` , putting the entire {{records}} in html or other

Answer (score 1):

*some reason my page loads before the arrays*

The functions provided as arguments to the Firebase methods are held by the Firebase API until data arrives from the server. Those functions are executed *asynchronously*. This means they are executed *after* the enclosing functions complete.

Changes to scope that occur asynchronously outside the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle will not trigger changes to the DOM. One technique to bring events into the AngularJS framework is to convert the ES6 promises to $q service promises:

```
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      $rootScope.userID = user.uid;

      // Run query to pull user records.
      //$timeout(function() {
        var userID = $rootScope.userID;
        var query = firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userID +'/movements/').orderByChild('created');

        //USE $q.when 
        $q.when(query.once("value")).then(function(value) {
            $scope.records = value;

              angular.forEach($scope.records, function(element) {
                $scope.recordsArray.push(element);
                $scope.labels.push(element.name);
                $scope.data.push(element.weight);
              });
        });
      //});
    } else {
      console.log("not signed in");
    }
  });
```

Use $q Service promises that are properly integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a `$q` promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> [-- AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)